# How do I set or change the layout of a sitecore template or item?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to change the layout of the home item, but the whole layout section seems like it doesn't do anything. How do I change the layout of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layouts are stored in the `/layouts/` directory, XSL transformations in the `/xsl/` directory.

You can create sublayouts (*.ascx) and layouts (*.aspx), which can be added to an item by selecting the item in the content tree -> click on the 'Presentation' tab -> click the 'Details' button.

You can get further details on [this page](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2010/03/Sitecore-simple-layout.aspx) and in the [Sitecore Developer Network](http://sdn.sitecore.net).

Comment: Hmm... The layouts list is empty and I can't set anything without setting a Layout. Any clues on that?